# How would I get the auto-genereated IDs off a batch of newly inserted data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the `.AddRange` function of Entity Framework Core to insert multiple entries into the database. The only method I can find of getting the auto-generated IDs from the ID column for this data is to loop though the entities and do  single query for each one. This seems highly inefficant and like I am missing something that is going to hit me in the face. What is the correct way to get back all the new IDs? My insert code:

```
public async Task<List<int>> UploadFile(Dictionary<IFormFile, string> files, string containerName, string connectionString)
    {
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var fileIDs = new List<int>();
        var filesInfo = new List<SiteFile>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<IFormFile, string> file in files)
        {
            var fileName = String.Concat(file.Value, ContentTypetoFileExtention.GetValueOrDefault(file.Key.ContentType));
            var blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            await blob.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = file.Key.ContentType });

            using (Stream stream = file.Key.OpenReadStream())
            {
                await blob.UploadAsync(stream);
            }

            filesInfo.Add(new SiteFile()
            {
                ContainerName = containerName,
                FileName = fileName
            });
        }

        await _siteDbContext.SiteFiles.AddRangeAsync(filesInfo);
        await _siteDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        //Get IDs, somehow?

        return fileIDs;
    }
```

Comment: So, here,`//Get IDs, somehow?` you would like to get each `inserted ID` or all ids together?

Comment: Get the id of each interested item and add it the fileIDs list so i can return a list all nee ids

Comment: Alright, I have the demo for you, just posting the answer, now. As you are inserting multiple data `AddRangeAsync(filesInfo)` so we will get all the inserted Ids together and it will not return null.

Comment: Great! When I go on lunch here at work I will look over your demo and learn. Thank you

Comment: Sure, have  a look on the demo. Feel free to share if you have any further concern on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to get back all the new IDs? My insert code:

Well, We can get the all the inserted ids by using a `select statement` over the inserted object. We can do as following:

```
   int[] ids = ObjectInserted.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();
```

**Note:** In your scenario it would be

```
int[] ids = filesInfo.Select(x => x.fileID).ToArray(); //Or
fileIDs = filesInfo.Select(x => x.fileID).ToList();
```

**Complete Demo:**

```
var studentList = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student() { Name="Kiron", Email = "email@someemail.com",Mobile ="123", Fname ="FName-1" },
                new Student() { Name="Matthew", Email = "matthew@someemail.com",Mobile ="234", Fname ="FName-2" },
                new Student() { Name="Guru Stron", Email = "Guru@someemail.com",Mobile ="635", Fname ="FName-3" },
                new Student() { Name="Farid", Email = "farid@someemail.com",Mobile ="6321", Fname ="FName-4" },

            };
            _studentDbContext.Students.AddRange(studentList);
            await _studentDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            int[] ids = studentList.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Further details can be found [here in the document](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/how-to-get-id-of-saved-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: So on the save call ef updates the entities in surdentlist with the ids? Interesting when I was trying to figure this out I could not find any evidance of that being the case. I kind of felt it was the case but I am not at the point of able to test yet. Thanks for the demo and info!

Comment: `"So on the save call ef updates the entities in surdentlist with the ids?`" Of course it will update the entities  once we call `_studentDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` sooner it will fetch all the `ids`. You can [`have a look  on this document`](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/how-to-get-id-of-saved-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: I feel stupid for not finding that when research but thank you  so much for linking that doc, it perfectly solves another problem I was trying to figure out! If you don't mind though,  looking at your demo you first fill an array with IDs then convert it to the list for return, why not just fill the list directly?

Comment: Yes we can do any suitable way we need to return the fetched IDs, As a matter of fact, I just written a quick demo for your context, thus, didn't consider that one. However, as per your scenario, you can do like this `fileIDs = filesInfo.Select(x => x.fileID).ToList();`. Because, you have already defined the list `var fileIDs` above

Answer (score 2):

Just selecting ids from `filesInfo` should work:

```cs
return filesInfo
    .Select(fi => fi.Id) // assuming property name is Id
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The IDs are generated at the db level during data insert by sql server. So unless ef is pulling the ids back for each one and updating the properties it would be null right?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete  When ``SaveChangesAsync`` done you can be sure that Ids are filled

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete EF pulls them back.